# How to compare multidimensional array with a common key pair using php?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

**Array A**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => test3
        )

)
```

**Array B**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [place] => madurai
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [place] => Trichy
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
            [place] => chennai
        )

)
```

I need a sample php code for array comparision. In array **a** collection of key pair (id) compare with every array key pair (id) in array **b**. I want to retrieve the following output.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => test1
            [place] => empty
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => test2
            [place] => Trichy
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => test3
            [place] => madurai
        )

)
```

Comment: So you want to do something like `INNER JOIN` on `id` in sql, but on PHP arrays?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: $arr2=array(array("id" => 3, "name" => "we"),
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "me"),
            array("id" => 55, "name" => "i")   
);$ids = array();

foreach($arr2 as $arr) {
   
   $ids[] = $arr['id'];
   
   
}

foreach($arr2 as $arr) {
   
   $names[] = $arr['name'];
   
   
}



foreach($arr1 as $arr) {

    
    if(in_array($arr['id'], $ids)) 
 {
       $arr3[] = $arr;
 
     } 
 else 
 {
       $arr4[] = $arr;
    }
}

Comment: $arr1=array(array("id" => 8, "name" => "test1"),  
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "test2"),  
            array("id" => 3, "name" => "test3")  
);
$arr2=array(array("id" => 3, "name" => "we"),
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "me"),
            array("id" => 55, "name" => "i")   
);
$arr2=array(array("id" => 3, "name" => "we"),
array("id" => 4, "name" => "me"),
array("id" => 55, "name" => "i")   
);$ids = array();foreach($arr2 as $arr) {$ids[] = $arr['id'];}
foreach($arr1 as $arr) {if(in_array($arr['id'], $ids)){$arr3[] = $arr;} else {$arr4[] = $arr;}}

Comment: @radhajesus Please post your code as an update to the question, not in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient method but try this

```
<?php

$arrayA=array();
$arrayA[0]["id"]=8;
$arrayA[0]["name"]="test1";
$arrayA[1]["id"]=4;
$arrayA[1]["name"]="test2";
$arrayA[2]["id"]=3;
$arrayA[2]["name"]="test3";

$arrayB=array();
$arrayB[0]["id"]=3;
$arrayB[0]["place"]="madurai";
$arrayB[1]["id"]=4;
$arrayB[1]["place"]="Trichy";
$arrayB[2]["id"]=55;
$arrayB[2]["place"]="chennai";

$places=Array();
$i=0;
foreach($arrayA as $itemA)
{
    $places[$i]["id"]=$itemA["id"];
    $places[$i]["name"]=$itemA["name"];
    $match=0;
    foreach($arrayB as $itemB)
    {
        if($itemA["id"]==$itemB["id"])
        {
            $places[$i]["place"]=$itemB["place"];
            $match=1;
        }
    }
    if($match==0)
    {
            $places[$i]["place"]="empty";
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($places);


?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help.Its useful for me.It retrieve only matching results. i want to retrieve match and non match results. please refer my question once again. now i have update the output.

Comment: for unmatched results, you can use array_diff(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thanks Hanky Panky!. its work now. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: glad it helped, you can accept the answer so it can help any other person in future for a similar need

Comment: Hi Hanky Panky! i need another help

Answer (score 0):

This code better illustrates your logic

```
<?php
$country1 = array("id" => "1", "country" => "Australia",);

$country2 = array("id" => "3", "country" => "India",);
$country3 = array("id" => "2", "country" => "USA",);

$array1 = array($country1, $country2, $country3);

$capital1 = array("id" => "1", "capital" => "Sydney",);

$capital2 = array("id" => "3","capital" => "Delhi",);

$capital3 = array("id" => "4","capital" => "Berne",);

$array2=array($capital1, $capital2, $capital3);

$size1 = count($array1);
$size2 = count($array2);

$j = 0;

while($j < $size2)
{
    $i=0;
    while($i < $size1)
    {
        if(($array1[$i]['id']) == ($array2[$j]['id']))
        { 
             echo $array2[$i]['capital']."is capital of ".$array1[$j]['country']."<br/>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $j++;
}

?>
```

this is a simple example for array of associative arrays .